Why different thickness of ring and disc for moment of inertia?
Why can not we use the differential disc approach for calculating the moment of inertia of solid sphere?
i.e. let $r\cos\theta$ be the radius of a disc of thickness $rd\theta$, at an angle of $\theta$ from centre. Why can't we proceed in this way?

As written it's not clear what you are asking, at least to me.

Hi Deepansh and welcome to the Physics SE. I have converted your equations to MathJax. Please check I have understood you correctly.

Are you thinking of a construction like this where you would sum the MOIs of the disks by integrating over  $\theta$?

The question isn't clear. Imagine you are trying to explain to a complete stranger what you have been deriving. Things which are obvious to you (since you are in the midst of the puzzle) aren't available or even introduced to others. A diagram may help, else a detailed description. We have no idea what $r,\theta$ are. Where 'the center' is. What $\theta$ is an angle between?  What do you mean by your 'differential disc approach' ? Once you add these details to the question, one can understand your doubt better. Cheers.
